# Exporting to CSV using R without symbols

Tags: r, csv, xlsx, r-rio

I am writing a script to automatically convert to csv, a long list of xlsx files. Currently using export function from the rio package.

Problem is, there comes symbols and characters in the csv files. On the other hand, converting to a csv using Microsoft excel File>Save as doesn't give any symbols.

I want the excel files not to have any of those symbols or characters.

Comment: This lacks sufficient context (e.g., sample data) to do more than opine what *might* be useful. Please make this question reproducible. Also, it seems that this is more likely a unicode issue (e.g., `iconv`), not a file read/write problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can first import the xlsx files with `readxl::read_xlsx`, and then convert it to csv with the base function `write.csv`: both encoding should keep the symbols.